# Is it possible to play a Games for Windows Live game and use Xbox Live at the same time?

Tags: xbox-network, games-for-windows-live

I bought Dawn of War 2 for the PC I ran into a problem:

When I play DoW2 it logs me into my Games for Windows/Xbox "Live" account, the same I use for my Xbox. This is normally just fine, but my wife really enjoys using Netflix Streaming on the Xbox. So when she fires up the Xbox when I'm in the middle of a DoW2 match, I'm booted out. The same happens to Netflix if I boot up DoW2.

I've attempted to explain the issue to both Microsoft support (no answer) and Relic (didn't understand my question).

Does anyone know a solution to this, other than using a different Live account for one or the other (need Live Gold to use Netflix, I'm not paying for two, and want same live account to keep achievements in the same spot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its like using the same account on two xbox.  You can't do it.

Now there are obvious reasons why Microsoft doesn't want you to be able to use the same account more than once (which are compounded by DLC), but the bottom line is: you can only be logged into the same account in one location at a time.

Now you might want to consider the new [Family Pack](http://majornelson.com/archive/2010/06/22/xbox-live-family-pack-coming-this-november.aspx), which is coming soon.  Or streaming your Netflix to a PC.

The short answer though, is: No

Comment: that was my conclusion as well. a human confirmation was all I needed /sadpanda

Comment: you can just make a different account for the pc, there arnt any decent crossover features anyway